# cannot store password when connection to CNAMEd RDP host

Tags: active-directory, remote-desktop

We have users using client pc/notebooks(domain joined) with windows 10/11 and default one server RDS setup installed on 2 (domain joined) servers.

We need to have CNAME pointing to the active RDP host. When users try to store passwords and connect they get password prompt with "...**because its identity is not fully verified**..."[image: Promt with error]

**Users can store their password when connecting to the hostname (A record) directly.**

I have tried to do the following:

1. configure the GPO "Allow delegeting default credentials with NTLM-only server authentication" - did not help
2. Disable NTLM completly - did not help

None of the above helped anyhow. What am I missing here?

Comment: Did you register an SPN for `TERMSRV/ts-eng-1...` on the account(s) hosting the RDP endpoint?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen this worked like charm! Thanks for the help!

Comment: Excellent, you're most welcome. I suspect you've managed to read up on SPNs in the meantime, but in short: the SPN tells the AD KDC "this is the account whose shared secret you need to use to encrypt kerberos tickets for this service".

Comment: OK, understand. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

The fix was to add the cname as SPN for the computer object in Active Directory.